# How to make PFX file from Symantec code?

Tags: windows, ssl, openssl, code-signing, symantec

I have password-protected `pfx` file and now it expired . but i renewed that with the help of `Symantec code signing certificate` .

```
Below is your Code Signing certificate:

certificate 

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
base-64 encoded data
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Below is the intermediate CA certificate:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
base-64 encoded data
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Below is your certificate in pkcs7 format:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
base-64 encoded data
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

But i don't get .cer and .key files . I know the main requirement is to install the certificate on a browser . So i have some doubt :

1. Q 1 :

Should i copy these values to text file  (intermediate CA certificate or certificate in pkcs7 format or certificate )? which extension should i use ? is it .cer file ?

2. Q 2 :

after that what i do ? install this certificate ? any setup by setup tutorial or video links ?

thanks